# Rails/Devise: Couldn't find User with 'id'=sign_out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm getting an error message from Rails that it could not find a user with id 'sign_out'. The error comes up when I try to log out of a user session. The application is looking at the GET route instead of the DELETE route that I would like it to.

I've looked through the other posts with similar errors and they suggest that the routes are not configured properly. But I can't seem to figure out what's going on with my application. I've tried several things:

- Switching the order of the devise routes and the user resources
- Calling out the delete method explicitly
- Various combinations of method/destory paths for the link to logout

None of these options seem to work for me.

Here are my relevant files:

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'welcome#index'
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:index,:show]

  resources :images, only: [:index, :show, :update]
  resources :challenges
end
```

I also tried nesting and calling out the path directly:

```
devise_for :users do
  get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end
resources :users, only: [:index,:show]
```

my link to log out:

```
%li= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete
```

Running rake routes (relevant routes):

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                       Controller#Action
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)         devise/sessions#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                  users#index
```

Using the "Log out" link gets this error:

```
Couldn't find User with 'id'=sign_out
```

and the parameters associated with the request are:

```
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"sign_out"}
```

And for whatever reason, the link still generates a GET request:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_out" for ::1 at 2015-12-25 03:35:11 -0600
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"sign_out"}
```

Does anyone have any recommendations on what to change/try next? Let me know if you need more information from any other files.

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript errors on the page? Are you including jquery_ujs in your application.js file?

Comment: No javascript errors that I can see. My application.js file is empty.

Comment: I just put in a bootstrap template today. But I was getting this error before that.

Comment: If it's empty, that's where your problem lies. You need to require jquery_ujs, like the standard Rails template file does.

Comment: Ah, good catch. I did just add those lines back:
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs

It looks like it still doesn't work though. Same error.
I tried restarting the server as well. :\

Comment: Ah, I didn't include the js file in my layout. I added it and got an InvalidAuthenticityToken error. But I made some progress! Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. My application.js file needed the defaulted comments:

   `//= require jquery`

   `//= require jquery_ujs`
2. My layouts/application.haml file needed the CSRF meta tags:

   `= csrf_meta_tags`

Thanks to sevenseacat for pointing me in the right direction!